# Adding additional files to a Trac plugin

Tags: plugins, trac

I am writing a plugin for Trac and want to put some additional files (e.g. css files) into my plugin.

I am using an egg-link to my source directory, and loading the plugin from there works, but the css file can not be found. So I thought maybe it searches relatively to the egg-link's path, but it didn't work neither.

Is it possible at all to add those files to the plugin, or do I have to put them in the script as strings? If it is possible, in which (relative) directory does it search for files when using an egg-link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static resources are made available using [ITemplateProvider](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.web.chrome.ITemplateProvider). Assume you have a typical directory structure like the following:

- `codereviewplugin`

  - `codereview`

    - `htdocs`

      - `css`

        - `codereview.css`

In one of your plugin's `Component` classes, which in this case it would likely be named `CodeReviewModule` in module `web_ui.py`, you'd implement `ITemplateProvider` with:

```
def get_htdocs_dirs(self):
    from pkg_resources import resource_filename
    return [('codereview', resource_filename(__name__, 'htdocs')]
```

You can then add the CSS file to a template using a call `add_stylesheet('codereview/css/codereview.css')`.

You also have to register the files in `setup.py`, otherwise it may work when installing the egg in editable mode (egg-link), but not in a normal egg installation:

```
packages=['codereview'],
package_data = {'codereview': ['htdocs/css/*.css'}
```

There are many examples in the Trac core, such as [Chrome](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.9/trac/web/chrome.py#L390).

Comment: Can I also read() the file and save it to a string variable instead of using add_stylesheet? I would like to have the css as a string to be able to use it in my code.

Comment: You can get the path to the file using `pkg_resources.resource_filename` as shown in the previous examples, then use `open` to read the file. What exactly do you want to do with the file contents after you have read them? If you wish to insert the contents into the page between `script` tags, then you may  need to use [ITemplateStreamFilter](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.web.api.ITemplateStreamFilter).

Comment: Rather than `ITemplateStreamFilter`,  you could implement `IRequestHandler` for a request to the stylesheet. See example in [WikiExtrasPlugin changeset 14311](https://trac-hacks.org/changeset/14311/wikiextrasplugin/trunk). A reasonable enhancement request might be to allow data to be passed to `add_stylesheet` for interpolating variables. This would be somewhat similar to [add_script_data](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.9/trac/web/chrome.py#L174). I'm not sure what the implementation would look this in this case though. Maybe the `IRequestFilter` pattern is the best to follow.

Comment: Also, I don't want to discourage you from using StackOverflow, but you will probably reach a more extensive audience of Trac users and developers by posting to the [trac-users mailing list](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList).